# Improve speed of COPY COMMAND in postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, copy, postgresql-performance

I would like to understand if increasing `work_mem` does help improving the speed of the `COPY` command.

Does `COPY` use `work_mem` or `maint_work_mem` extensively?

Comment: Are you using `COPY` for a table, or for the results of a query? If the latter, then optimizing the query will be the way to speed things up.

Comment: It's COPY for a table which is 250 GB and I am importing it from S3 to RDS Postgres

Answer (score 8):

No, `COPY` does not need a lot of memory.

There are two things to speed up `COPY`:

- Remove any indexes and constraints on the table before you `COPY` into it.
- Increase `max_wal_size` so that you don't get more checkpoints than necessary.

  Of course, if you `COPY` into an `UNLOGGED` table, it will be even faster.